# Server.Execute() opens the new page in current page

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I used server.execute to hide my query string in URL, but I found another problem, when I'm in page 1 and clicks a button that transfers me to page 2 , page 1 content is still displayed in the page with the content of page 2. Both pages are shown to me. How can I resolve this ?

example of my code. in page 1 , there is a button, I add this code in click event.

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Server.Execute("Page2.aspx?Name=john");
}
```

in page 2 , there is a text box that reads the query string value.

```
  TextBox1.Text = Request.QueryString["Name"].ToString();
```

I send multiple values in query string but this is just an example. however, page 1 and page 2 contents are both displayed in one page after clicking the button that should transfer me to page 2.

Comment: this server.execute is for getting output of a url to string using StringWriter, what are you trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As server.execute transfer control back to original page and continue execution of it also, therefor you are seeing output of both pages. To Transfer the request completely use [Server.TransferRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647705(v=vs.110).aspx)

**Page1.aspx** : add query string values as `NameValueCollection`

```
            NameValueCollection nv = new NameValueCollection();
            nv.Add("Name","john");
            Server.TransferRequest("Page2.aspx",true,"GET", nv);
```

**Page2.aspx** : get your values from `Request.Header`

```
         TextBox1.Text = Request.Headers.Get("Name");
```

Comment: Actually I preferred to use Server.Execute() to prevent the stated error here. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/312629/prb-threadabortexception-occurs-if-you-use-response.end,-response.redirect,-or-server.transfer

Comment: I have updated my answer, you should add your code to the question to investigate your requirement in more depth.

Answer (score 1):

Use Server.Transfer instead of Server.Execute.
Check this out to understand the difference.
[Difference between both](http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/144239-Difference-between-Server-Transfer-Server-Execute.aspx)

> When Server.Execute is used, a URL is passed to it as a parameter, and the control moves to this new page. Execution of code happens on the new page. Once code execution gets over, the control returns to the initial page, just after where it was called. However, in the case of Server.Transfer, it works very much the same, the difference being the execution stops at the new page itself (means the control is'nt returned to the calling page).
>   In both the cases, the URL in the browser remains the first page url (does'nt refresh to the new page URL) as the browser is'nt requested to do so.

Comment: Actually I preferred to use Server.Execute() to prevent the stated error here. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/312629/prb-threadabortexception-occurs-if-you-use-response.end,-response.redirect,-or-server.transfer

Comment: You can assign a postbackurl property to the button and use it for cross page posting. Check this link : [link]( https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.postbackurl(v=vs.110).aspx)